# Not able to remove space after each character for ( Belarusian langugae) language

Tags: android, textview, typeface

I used google vision API to translate text. I show the translated text in a dynamic_text view ( block-wise). For some language, like Belarusian, it shows space after each character. As it is office project, I am not able to post a screenshot. How to remove the space after each character?

Comment: how do you diferentiate if it is a *space between each character*, or that is for example *a single-character word*?

Comment: Actually when I set the string in textview, it shows string has a space after each character, but when I see the logcat, there is no space.

Comment: the there is no space in fact. That is likely a TextView lag. Do you use cuustom font?

Comment: hmm.  It works in static textview perfectly but fails to the dynamic textview

Comment: what is special about dynamic TextView? Do you change anything in it?

Comment: I used dynamic text to show translated text on original text

Comment: the question is **how** you did it.